# How to compare all files in a list to find duplicates

Tags: c#, file, compare

I need a method to compare files in a directory.
First I pick a rootfolder to get all the files inside it.

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileList = rootDir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

My first attempt was to use two foreach-loops

```
        foreach (FileInfo file1 in fileList)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo file2 in fileList)
            {
                if (file2.FullName != file1.FullName && file2.Length == file1.Length)
                {
                    tb_result.AppendText("\r\n" + file1.FullName + "\r\n" + file2.FullName + "\r\n");
                }
            }
```

Now I have to use another list to save the already used Filenames to prevent that my application finds the same used File.

Example:

- rootdir

  - test1
  - test2
  - test3
- subdir

  - test1

The method finds test1 in rootdir and test1 in subdir. Later it finds test1 in subdir and test1 in rootdir and prints this out too.

Is there a way to remove used elements from the list or is there a better way to compare a directory with subdirectories?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly clear what you are looking for, but you can probably:

```
// We group by size, and we take only the groups that have multiple files
var grouped = fileList.GroupBy(x => x.Length).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);

// Each group is "keyed"/"grouped" by size
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}", group.Key);

    foreach (var file in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" {0}", file.FullName);
    }
}
```

Note that while your method is `O(n^2)` (each file is compared with each other), and even Guillaume's one is `O(n^2)` (but shorter, because he do *n*(n-1)/2* comparisons or something similar), this one should be `O(n)` (because `GroupBy` should be `O(n)` if it internally uses an hashtable)

Answer (score 0):

Change your double loop to avoid checking multiple times the same items.

```
    FileInfo[] fileList = rootDir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        FileInfo file1 = fileList[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j < fileList.Length; j++)
        {
            FileInfo file2 = fileList[j];
            if (file2.Length == file1.Length)
            {
                tb_result.AppendText("\r\n" + file1.FullName + "\r\n" + file2.FullName + "\r\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: perfect, thanks for your quick anwser. I tried it out and it works.

Comment: I think `file2.FullName != file1.FullName &&` could be removed.